# Git: How to "undo" a merge

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

The situation:
Starting with the Master at `A` I branched and made some changes at `B` then merged that branch back in `(C)`. After making some more changes I was at `D` but found I needed to deploy the code without the changes that happened in the branch. If I hand't merged it that would have been fine.

```
A_______C___D
 \     /
  \_B_/
```

Firstly I'd like to know what I should have done from here to deploy the code as if the merge never happened. Note: none of the same files that were edited in the branch have been edited in the master.

Secondly...

I didn't have time to work out the best method to deal with this, so I deleted the files which the branch added, and manually reverted a few edits made in the branch then commited the result for deployment (`F`)

```
A_______C___D___F
 \     /
  \_B_/
```

I want to be able to keep developing the branch and merge any changes from the master into it to keep it up to date, but if I do that the stuff I did to create `F` will be merged in and cause the files to be deleted and the edits to be reverted. What is the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use rebase to do that in one step:

```
git rebase --onto A C D
```

I just tested this, with appropriate results:

```
$ edit test.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -mA
$ git checkout -b the_branch
$ edit test.txt
$ git commit -a -mB
$ git checkout master
$ git merge master the_branch --no-ff
$ edit test.txt
$ git commit -a -mD
```

From here you have the situation you described.
Then:

```
$ git rebase --onto <SHA1-for-A> <SHA1-for-C> master
```

rebases commits from C (excluded) to master, onto A.
I needed to fix some conflicts since I modified at the same places in B and D, but I think you won't.

```
   _D'
  /
 /
A_______C___D
 \     /
  \_B_/
```

Doc about `git rebase --onto`, which is more or less your situation:
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

---

If you had:

```
A_______C___D___F
 \     /
  \_B_/
```

, then you have now:

```
   _D'___F'_(master)
  /
 /
A_______C___D___F
 \     /
  \_B_/(the_branch)
```

From here, merging the changes in master into the branch is easy. Discard the commit `F'` altogether.

```
$ git checkout master # if you were not here already
$ git branch old_fix  # if you want to be able to return to F' later
$ git reset --hard <SHA1-to-D'>
```

After the commands above you have:

```
     (master)
    /
   _D'___F'_(old_fix)
  /
 /
A_______C___D___F
 \     /
  \_B_/(the_branch)
```

To merge updates of master into the_branch:

```
$ git checkout the_branch
$ git merge master
```

... and fix the conflicts.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll use this in future (if being more careful with my merges fails to work). See @terminus's answer for what I did. I think it achieved pretty much the same result as your answer.

Answer (score 6):

The obvious solution is to reset to `A`, reapply all patches manually and resolve conflicts (which you won't have).

Alternatively you can just `git revert` patch `B` but that will create a new commit.

Although Gauthier's answer is better.

Comment: Thanks, After reading this I looked into patches and ended up here: http://www.gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/04/pick-out-individual-commits.html So I Branched off A and cherry-picked D and F, then merged the result into the original branch to bring it up to date.

Comment: Did you really cherry-pick F? I thought F was only to reverse B and C, so it had nothing to do after C'?

Comment: Sorry, now I'm not sure. Perhaps I did but didn't really need to.